# Why can a weak member be nulled in an instance method before the method is finished?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

And why can it vary between Debug/Release/Simulator/Device combinations? (Sample code below.)

I inherited some code that "works" in the simulator and on devices in Debug, but not on a device in Release (used to with last LLVM). It's related to ARC and a weak property (which should have been strong), but I don't understand fully what's happening and am hoping someone can explain it to me and why it varies between Debug/Release/Device/Simulator.

I created a simple sample project that demonstrates this, with all code in AppDelegate.m as included below. When run in the simulator, the logged output is:

```
-[BaseThingMaker baseMakeThing]: returning a Thing
-[ThingMaker makeThing]: returning a Thing
-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: got a Thing
```

When run on the device, the logged output is:

```
-[BaseThingMaker baseMakeThing]: returning a Thing
-[ThingMaker makeThing]: returning a (null)
-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: got a (null)
```

On a device (in Debug or Release), the weak `self.thing` in `ThingMaker` is null even for the log message before the method is complete. On the simulator, the `self.thing` object is returned.

Sample code from Single Window App (AppDelegate.m):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface Thing : NSObject
@end
@implementation Thing
@end

@interface BaseThingMaker : NSObject
-(Thing *)baseMakeThing;
@end

@implementation BaseThingMaker
-(Thing *)baseMakeThing
{
    Thing *thing = [Thing new];
    NSLog(@"%s: returning a %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, NSStringFromClass([thing class]));
    return thing;
}
@end


@interface ThingMaker : NSObject
- (id)makeThing;
@end

@interface ThingMaker ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) id thing;
@end

@implementation ThingMaker
- (id)makeThing
{
    BaseThingMaker *baseThingMaker = [BaseThingMaker new];
    self.thing = [baseThingMaker baseMakeThing];
    NSLog(@"%s: returning a %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, NSStringFromClass([self.thing class]));
    return self.thing;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ThingMaker *thingMaker = [ThingMaker new];
    id thingIWant = [thingMaker makeThing];
    NSLog(@"%s: got a %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, NSStringFromClass([thingIWant class]));
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `baseMakeThing` does not return an object its call owns, in this case it returns an autoreleased object. If it is an autoreleased object it will have an owner - the autorelease pool - until the pool it emptied when the run loop cycles around. So the assignment to the weak property will be valid until that happens, and the code will *appear* to work...

**Unless** the compiler optimises, instead of retaining an autoreleased object the compiler can sometimes pull the object out of the autorelease pool and take ownership that way. If the compiler does this then immediately after the assignment to the weak property the compiler can relinquish ownership, as the reference is not used later in `makeThing`, and this will in turn null the weak property...

The differences you are seeing are down to how much optimisation the compiler is doing depending on the type of build.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. It's what my intuition was saying, but it just seems strange that the weak ivar didn't even stick around long enough for the NSLog call. Also, I believe my question is basically a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118909/arc-weak-ivar-released-before-being-returned-when-building-for-release-not-de?rq=1).

Comment: @JefferyRPrice - The compiler is free to drop its reference once it is no longer referenced, which can mean before the `NSLog`. Change the name of `baseMakeThing` to `newBaseMakeThing` - which by naming convention is in the `new` family which like the `init` family returns an owned object. Now you'll get a warning that the object will be released immediately after the assignment to the weak property. (You don't get a warning as the method returns an object the caller doesn't own, not one that nobody owns, and so ARC is not responsible for releasing it.)

Comment: @sbooth - changing the name is easier, but yes you could add an attribute but isn't that the wrong one? The name change is so that it doesn't return an autoreleased object but one the caller owns.

Comment: @CRD - Thanks again. It's interesting (meaning it doesn't feel right to me) that just changing the method to using the `new` naming convention is enough to trigger the compiler warning ("Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment"). It feels like that warning should have happened without the `new`. Of course everything works if the ivar was just `strong` to begin with.

Comment: @JefferyRPrice - The warning triggers because the ownership changes when the name changes, the warning is not correct before that. As you say, that such behaviour is implicitly dependant on naming can make understanding harder.

Comment: @CRD you're right, the attribute should be `__attribute__((ns_returns_retained))`.  I've deleted the old comment to prevent confusion